# If else statement with multiple answers

Tags: javascript, if-statement, var

I am sort of new at this, but I am trying to make write a bit of javascript code and am having some trouble.

I have the following code and have checked it over and over again and cannot find the problem. I have run it through jsfiddle, and I cannot figure out where I went wrong.

```js
var question = prompt('Who shot Abraham Lincoln?');
if (question == 'john wilkes booth' || question == 'John Booth' || question == 'John Wilkes Booth') {
    alert("That\'s Right!");
    window.location.href = 'q2.html';
} else {
    alert('Sorry, that\'s not right.');
    alert('Please try again');
    history.refresh();
}
```

Comment: remove the semicolon from your if statement 'John Wilkes Booth');

Comment: @Prabhu You should list that as an answer so he can mark it as answered.

Comment: May like to convert the answer to `.toLowerCase()` before comparing to like. No need to escape ' in `"` and call the var `answer`!

Comment: like @Prabhu  said remove your semicolon.. in your fiddle you have semicolon after else too...

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work! I knew it was probably just a small error.

Comment: Alternative: http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/0axc8rpc/2/

Comment: @AlexK. could you elaborate on the .toLowerCase()? Because I tried it and it did not work and I do not want to post a new question.

Comment: If `question ` is `"john"` its not the same as `"John"` because the case is different, but after `question = question.toLowerCase();` the `"JoHn"` entered by the user will always equal `"john"` because you have changed it to lower case.

Comment: @AlexK. Okay thanks. Also the alternative you provided on jsfiddle proved helpful, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got extra semicolon ';' in row 3 of your question example.
And in jsFiddle which you provided there is an extra semicolon after else

Answer (score 0):

it is because of semicolons in lines `3` and `5` this will work:

```js
    var question = prompt('Who shot Abraham Lincoln?');
    if (question == 'john wilkes booth' || question == 'John Booth' || question ==
        'John Wilkes Booth') {
        alert("That\'s Right!"); window.location.href = 'q2.html';
    } else 
    {
        alert("Sorry, that\'s not right.");
        alert('Please try again');
        history.refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch/case:

```
var question = prompt('Who shot Abraham Lincoln?');
switch (question) {
    case 'john wilkes booth':
    case 'John Booth':
    case 'John Wilkes Booth':
            alert("That\'s Right!"); window.location.href = 'q2.html'; break;
    default:
            alert("Sorry, that\'s not right.");
            alert('Please try again');
            history.refresh();
    break;
}
```

Or better, I think:

```
var question = prompt('Who shot Abraham Lincoln?');
if (new RegExp("john( wilkes)? booth", "gi").test(question))
{
    alert("That\'s Right!"); window.location.href = 'q2.html';
}
else 
{
    alert("Sorry, that\'s not right.");
    alert('Please try again');
    history.refresh();
}
```